# How to execute PRINT command from windows Pocket PC using Bluetooth (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, printers, pocketpc

I want to print from windows pocket PC to my Bluetooth printer.

Comment: This question is unclear as is. If you found someone that still remembers Pocket PC (it's over 15 years old after all) they'd tell you there was no printing available back then, and ask whether you use the .NET Compact Framework or not. If you search SO for `Compact Framework Printing` you'll get some answers, although not very encouraging. Specific POS printers may have CF SDKs. Most answers mention the PrinterCE library.

Answer (score 0):

PocketPC and Windows Mobile or Windows Embedded Handheld 6.x do not have a printing subsystem as full desktop windows.

If you are lucky, the Printer vendor has an SDK for Windows Mobile 5.x/6.x or Windows CE 5. If not, it is up to you to open a connection to the printer (BT stream or Virtual COM port) and send printer language commands directly to the printer.

Like said, there is for example PrinterCE as a general SDK for some printers.